# Unknown SQL Server Wait Types

Tags: sql-server-2014

We're using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise and for some tables we're using a clustered columnstore index.

Sometimes when running queries, we're seeing unknown wait types like `HTREBUILD`, `HTREPARTITION`, `HTMEMO`. Searching with Google didn't give any meaningful results.

Does anyone know what these are, and if so, can you please give us some background?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108062/what-do-the-ht-wait-types-mean-htrepartition-htdelete this is a duplicate.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83fe7593-5184-4bc9-9e6b-aafa8e98116d/htmemo-waittype-in-sql-server-2014culstered-columnstore-index?forum=transactsql more info here

Answer (score 0):

> HTREBUILD, HTREPARTITION, [HTMEMO](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/htmemo/),  HTDELETE

This wait type (and the other HT* waits) is when a thread is waiting for access to the shared hash table used during batch-mode processing. 
**SQL Server 2012 used to use a hash table per thread** and **SQL Server 2014** **now uses a shared hash table.**

Basically; SQL Server 2014 now uses one shared hash table instead of per-thread copy.

This change was made to reduce the amount of memory required for the hash table, but comes at the expense of these waits when synchronizing access to the hash table. Typically these waits occur when queries involve columnstore indexes, but they can also occur without columnstore indexes being involved if a hash operator runs in batch mode.

**Using one shared hash table instead of per-thread copy :**

Provides the benefit of significantly lowering the amount of memory
required to persist the hash table but, as you can imagine, the multiple
threads depending on that single copy of the hash table must synchronize with
each other before, for example, deallocating the hash table. To do so, those
threads wait on the [HTDELETE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8579f864-cbdc-49b9-be26-d47af61df56d/sql-server-2014-wait-info-htdelete?forum=sql14db) (Hash Table DELETE) wait type.